# Scaling data to a sample that is neither training nor validation. Is this data leakage?

Tags: machine-learning, data-preprocessing, train-test-split, data-leakage

TL;DR: Data being scaled to a sample that is neither training nor validation. Is this data leakage?

Hi,

I have a data set from samples that are distributed on a plate. Precisely, there are 96 wells where 3 are sample controls, 5 are plate controls, 2 are negative controls, and the rest (86) are actual samples. Each sample is quantified for over 5000 proteins, and there are spike-in controls that are quantified as well. Hence, there are two levels of control, on the sample level (spike-in) and on the plate level (plate control). Each protein gets a "count" data, and this count is later transformed into an arbitrary unit for statistical analysis:

$$
Step1_{protein X} = log2(\frac{Count_{[protein X]}}{Count_{[spike-in]}})
$$

$$
Step2_{proteinX} = Step1_{proteinX} - median(Step1_{[\textit{proteinX from plate controls}]})
$$

Step 1 is done for all proteins in all samples, including the plate controls. Let's say we are measuring Albumin (ALB); hence, I would have Step1 for ALB in sample "Z", and Step1 for ALB in all 5 plate controls. The Step2 for ALB in sample "Z" is then calculated by subtracting the median of all 5 Step1 ALB of plate controls. Does this make any sense?

Of note, samples spread out over multiple plates will be normalized by their corresponding plate controls.

From my readings in Google and Stack, I learned that traditional scaling of the data should be done separately for training and validation because we would be borrowing data from the validation when working with the training data. However, **in my problem, data is being scaled to a sample that is neither training nor validation. Does it look like data leakage?**

My interpretation is that this is not data leakage. Even though I am applying the same mathematical procedure for both training and validation, I am not using actual information from my validation cohort, so it looks fine to me.

I assume this would be common in biological studies, but I didn't find anything on Stack.